# Writing a 3D Matlab matrix to a file as 1D and read it back in C

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a three-dimensional Matlab matrix, with the shape `3x4x5` . Now I want to write this Matrix to a .txt file 1-dimensional and read it back out in C.

However, the numbers written should be the x and the y dimension first (so `4x5`) followed by z-dimension (3).

Sample code for filling the matrix:

```
duneven = 1:3*4*5
duneven = reshape(duneven,[3 4 5]);
```

I hoped to get this effect by permuting the matrix like this:

```
duneven = permute(duneven,[3 1 2]);
```

And writing it out like this:

```
fp = fopen('testuneven.txt','w');
fprintf(fp,'%f ',duneven);
fclose(fp);
```

However, reading it in C - like this:

```
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("testuneven.txt","r");

for(int i = 0; i < 3*4*5;i++){
   float var;
   fscanf(fp,"%f ",&var);
   printf("%f ",var);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Reading it out in Matlab gives the same output. Furthermore, cat-ing out the file in the shell gives back the same results. So the issue is located in the Matlab code

Does not give back the desired output. Instead it prints out the first cols. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you check the file to read? Weren't there any extra characters such as braces, comma, etc?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Yes I checked it and edited the question

Comment: Please show us the `testuneven.txt`file. And show also the actual and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that matlab writes out the matrix column wise, while C reads it in row wise. To be sure, that it is written correctly, I have done the following:

```
duneven = 1:3*4*5
duneven = reshape(duneven,[3 4 5]);

%in case that the shape is not known
duneven_shape = size(duneven);


fileID = fopen('testunven.txt','w')

for i=1:duneven_shape(1)
    v = reshape(squeeze(duneven (i,:,:))',[1 duneven_shape(2)*duneven_shape(3)]);
    fprintf(fileID,"%f ",v);
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mixed up the order in your permute() call. Your inital discription of the desired Dimension order stats 4x5 and then 3

your code

```
duneven = 1:3*4*5
duneven = reshape(duneven,[3 4 5]);
duneven = permute(duneven,[3 1 2])
```

produces 5x3x4.

consider using `duneven = permute(duneven,[2 3 1])`